# How to share common code blocks between maven profiles?

Tags: maven

I have two maven profiles, the only difference is a  line. Other than that the two profiles are identical. Is there a way to share the common code blocks in the POM without copy/paste? For example, declare a base profile and inherit it, and change the corresponding line in the children? I do not want to use any environmental variable approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>parent-profile</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <!-- common config -->
 </profile>

 <profile>
   <id>profile-a</id>
     <!-- specific config for a -->
 </profile>

 <profile>
   <id>profile-b</id>
     <!-- specific config for b -->
   </profile>
 </profiles>
```

And just run: 
`mvn args -P profile-a` or `mvn args -P profile-b`

And if you dont want the parent-profile to be active by default, just delete the specified line and every time you wish to activate one profile, add the parent profile to mvn like: 
`mvn args -P parent-profile, profile-a` or `mvn args -P parent-profile, profile-b`